# scala: Error occurred during initialization of VM on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: scala, error-handling, virtual-machine, sbt

I tried to work with easy example of scala language.
I installed `sbt` successfully. When run `sbt -h` I see help message from sbt:

```
Usage: sbt [options]

  -h | -help         print this message
  -v | -verbose      this runner is chattier
  -d | -debug        set sbt log level to debug
  -no-colors         disable ANSI color codes
  -sbt-create        start sbt even if current directory contains no sbt project
  -sbt-dir   <path>  path to global settings/plugins directory (default: ~/.sbt)
  -sbt-boot  <path>  path to shared boot directory (default: ~/.sbt/boot in 0.11 series)
  -ivy       <path>  path to local Ivy repository (default: ~/.ivy2)
  -mem    <integer>  set memory options (default: 1536, which is -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=192m) ....
```

but when I tried to run in the directory with scala assignments (it's Coursera course) I caught error:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~/scala/example$ sbt
Detected sbt version 0.12.1
Starting sbt: invoke with -help for other options
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

but it should open the sbt command prompt. Smt like this:

```
shell$ cd /path/to/progfun-project-directory                        # This is the shell of the operating system
shell$ sbt
> _                                                                 # This is the sbt shell
```

**UPDATE:**

After I add this following line

`java -Xms64M -Xmx256M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=64M -jar`dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"`

at `/usr/bin` I see next output:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:/usr/bin$ sbt
bash: /usr/bin/sbt: Permission denied
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:/usr/bin$ sudo sbt
sudo: sbt: command not found
```

***- Why this happen?

 - How to solve this issue?***

Comment: I suggest you look up the comments on coursera's course discussion threads. If anyone had the same problem, you'll get more contextualized information there.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral Course finished it's archive I don't know if smb can give any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, The example folder name (and the folder name that you have installed sbt)  cannot include "!". this probably applies to other special characters as well. Even, I recommend to install SBT in a folder that has no space on its path (and the same thing for examples folder).

For example, if you have installed SBT (or examples folder) on a path like:

```
/Users/dashti/My Programs/sbt-0.12.1
```

You can re-install it a path like:

```
/Users/dashti/MyPrograms/sbt-0.12.1
```

By applying this naming change, if the error is gone, please ignore the rest of this post.

Otherwise, to fix the mentioned error, first find sbt executable script, then edit it and correct any problem in it:

If you are using a UNIX-based operating system, please follow these steps:

1- Find SBT: Open a terminal and type this command:

```
which sbt
```

and you will receive a path like:

```
/Users/dashti/Documents/scala-2.10.0/bin/sbt
```

and in this file, there is a command for executing a java program, like:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

2- Edit sbt script: by entering this command in terminal:

```
vim /Users/dashti/Documents/scala-2.10.0/bin/sbt
```

you will be able to edit this file and maybe you should change the memory usage arguments to a lower specification ( You should think about whether you have enough RAM to be running the sbt). For example, this one will be a better choice:

```
java -Xms64M -Xmx256M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=64M -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

Comment: I found only this line - `echo "-Xms${mem}m -Xmx${mem}m -XX:MaxPermSize=${perm}m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=${codecache}m"`. But it looks a little weird to change [this line at this function](http://pastebin.com/rhNyebM5)?

Comment: You can replace the whole content of this "sbt" file, with: java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"

Comment: Can I add `.old` to current `sbt` file and create new with the same name and only one line: `java ....`?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's better to create a backup from previous file and creating a new executable file with this new content, but do not forget to make the new file executable. For simplicity, you'd better just copy current script under another name with this command: "cp sbt sbt.backup" and then edit the current sbt file using "vim sbt".

Comment: I maybe miss smt I created `sbt.backup` and changed content of file to correct. But now after `sbt` output looks - `Error: Unable to access jarfile /usr/bin/sbt-launch.jar`. What's wrong?

Comment: Either put a copy of sbt-launch.jar in /usr/bin, or correct its path inside the java arguments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35217/discussion-between-nazar-art-and-mohammad-dashti)

Comment: FWIW, you also need to find the default_sbt_mem setting in the sbt file and that also needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

SBT needs more memory allocated to the JVM.

This can be done in `build.sbt`:

```
javaOptions ++= Seq(
    "-Xms64m",
    "-Xmx256M",
    "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled",
    "-XX:MaxPermSize=64M"
);
```

Creating an `sbt` file(no extentions) and running `./sbt` is better, but with the code below(@MohammadDashti's suggestion), `sbt-launch.jar` needs to be in the project folder.

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled \
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

Later you could add `javaagent:/path/to/jrebel -Drebel.remoting_plugin=true` and re-deploy changes on save with a free JRebel for Scala license.